# Asymptotic does not give asymptotic?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, asymptotics

Expression `Asymptotic[Exp[(1 + E^x)/(1 + x)], x -> Infinity]` gives `Exp[(1 + E^x)/x]` as  the answer but these functions are not asymptotes! Their ratio goes to infinity:

`Limit[Exp[((1 + E^x)/x)]/Exp[(1 + E^x)/(1 + x)], x -> Infinity]`

`Out=Infinity`

How the hell they can be asymptotes?

Comment: Maybe they're not. Maybe it's a bug.

Comment: 1+x turns to 0 in -1, so there may be a vertical asymptote there, indeed right limit does give +Infinity. There is also a Limit at -Infinity. So there is a horizontal asymptote at y=1. And there is no oblique asymtotes after checking.

Comment: y=1 is horizontal asymtote of Exp[(1 + E^x)/x] too, but Exp[(1 + E^x)/x] ideally describes behaviour at -Infinity. So Asymptotic does not give a classic asymptote, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote#Curvilinear_asymptotes.

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников `Asymptotic` function is not meant to give straight lines. And its second argument specifies behavior where we are interested in.

Comment: I find it as a bug. I think `Asymptotic[Exp[(1 + E^x)/(1 + x)], x -> Infinity]` should return `Exp[(1 + E^x)/(1 + x)]`.

Comment: Or `Exp[(E^x)/(1 + x)]`.

Comment: Ah, yes, this is only correct for -Infinity. In fact it does somehow print same for -Infinity.

Comment: It's often useful to mention which version of Mathematica you're using. If you suspect a bug it's mandatory.

Comment: This is all 13.1.